# Distribute extra tax cents using CTE

Tags: sql, loops, common-table-expression

I have a table of tax data like this

```
DECLARE @TaxSummary TABLE(
    TaxRegionType           SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    ActualRegionTaxTotal    NUMERIC(10,2) NULL,
    LineRegionTaxTotal      NUMERIC(10,2) NULL,
    ExtendedRegionTaxTotal  Numeric(14,6) NULL
)
```

And I have a set number of cents to distribute to each region type in that table...let's say I have 5 extra cents so I have

```
Declare @Cents int = 5

Declare @Delta = 0.01
```

And currently I update the table with a while loop like this

```
SET @Count = 0
    WHILE (@Count < @Cents)
      BEGIN
        SET @Count = @Count + 1

            UPDATE @TaxSummary
            SET ActualRegionTaxTotal = ActualRegionTaxTotal + @Delta
            WHERE TaxRegionType =
            (SELECT TOP(1) TaxRegionType
            FROM @TaxSummary
            WHERE ExtendedRegionTaxTotal <> 0
            ORDER BY ExtendedRegionTaxTotal-ActualRegionTaxTotal DESC)

      END
```

Is there a way this can be done using a CTE?  Or non-loop?  Basically I want to add one cent to each of the rows starting at the row with the biggest difference and keep adding to the row with the biggest difference until all the extra cents are used.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: This is a very good question.  I keep wondering if there is a set-based solution for this, that doesn't require looping.  I think the answer is "yes", if you have cumulative sums and lead/lag functionality.  However, neither of these are readily available in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

This may give you a general idea to help get you started - just add a cent to each row until the row number from the inline view is equal to the extra you are trying to lose:

```
declare @cents int = 5

select
region,
tax old_tax,
tax + case when rn <= @cents then 0.01 else 0 end new_tax

from
(
select
region, 
tax,
row_number () over (partition by null order by tax desc) rn

from 
dbo.taxsummary 
) d
```

Comment: Hmmm, I can't figure out how to use that snippet to help get what I want

Comment: Try running it against some sample data and you'll see that using the analytic function row_number in the inline view enables you to step down the rows one by one. The outer part of the query shows how you can stop adding cents when you have used them all. You can then wrap an update statement around the whole thing.

Comment: See answer I posted of why I am confused and what I have executing...thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is what I have and it only sets new_tax for each region to 10.01 so it only uses 2 cents and not all 5.....that is why I am confused...am I missing something?

```
DECLARE
    @OrderTotalTax      NUMERIC(10,2),
    @CollectedTax       NUMERIC(10,2),
    @RegionTotalTax     NUMERIC(10,2)

DECLARE @TaxSummary TABLE
(
    TaxRegionType           SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    ActualRegionTaxTotal    NUMERIC(10,2) NULL,
    LineRegionTaxTotal      NUMERIC(10,2) NULL,
    ExtendedRegionTaxTotal  Numeric(14,6) NULL
)


insert into @TaxSummary (TaxRegionType, ActualRegionTaxTotal, LineRegionTaxTotal,
ExtendedRegionTaxTotal )
values ( 1, 10.00, 0, 10.04 )

insert into @TaxSummary (TaxRegionType, ActualRegionTaxTotal, LineRegionTaxTotal,
ExtendedRegionTaxTotal )
values ( 2, 10.00, 0, 10.01 )

-- RegionTotalTax = 20.00
SELECT @RegionTotalTax = SUM(ActualRegionTaxTotal) from @TaxSummary

Declare @Cents int = 0

set @OrderTotalTax = 20.05


-- Cents will be 20.05-20.00*100 = 5
SET @Cents = ABS((@OrderTotalTax - @RegionTotalTax) * 100)

-- Distribute one cent at a time
Declare @Delta DECIMAL(18,2) = 0.01

select
TaxRegionType,
ActualRegionTaxTotal old_tax,
ActualRegionTaxTotal + case when rn <= @Cents then 0.01 else 0 end new_tax
from
(
select
TaxRegionType, 
ActualRegionTaxTotal,
row_number () over (partition by null order by ExtendedRegionTaxTotal-
ActualRegionTaxTotal desc) rn
from 
@TaxSummary 
) d
```

Comment: You only have 2 rows in TaxSummary so it's only using 2 cents (1 per row). If you need more cents per row then we need to first calculate the minimum number of cents per TaxRegionType so that the entire 5 cents is used (instead of "when rn <= Cents then 0.01" we need " when rn <= Cents then CentsPerRegion". CentsperRegion will be ceiling (num of cents/num of regions). Lastly:CentsPerRegion may be too big for the last region, so work out the num cents left over and change case statement to: ..when rn < Cents... when rn=Cents then CentsLeft ...(AT chars omitted - only one allowed in comments!)